# Write a Junit for a protected void method without arguments

Tags: java, junit

Write a Junit test case for a protected void method without arguments, which does nothing.

```
protected void init() {
    i=10;
    j=20;
}
```

Now, I want to write a Junit for `init()` method which does nothing apart from initialization. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: check `i` and `j` before and after calling it.

Comment: to second Oleg's thought, `assert` their values *after calling the method* to be equal to what you have initialized them in the method.

Comment: thanks Oleg. Instead of i and j, i have database connections, i need to ignore them. i.e.. when the init() method is invoked, i should return nothing. So, how do we mock this? Thanks.

Comment: Your init changes the state of your object in some way (in your case obviously open a database connection), and you test that state...

Comment: How did `i=10;j=20;` became a database connection?! Ask a normal question with your actual problem.

Comment: I just gave a sample there. My main moto is to mock the protected void method whatever the lines of code it may contain and return nothing. Thanks.

Comment: But if you mock the method then you don't test it

Comment: If this is an init method that is called from outside then this should be public API and have public or 'default' as modifier. Testing a public method should then be fairly easy. If this init method is called from a constructor and therefore not public it should be final and be tested through the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check that the fields are set after the initialization you do exactly that.

```
@Test
public void fieldAreInitialized()
{
    YourClass x = new YourClass();
    x.methodWhichCallsInit();

    Assert.assertEquals(10, x.getI());
    Assert.assertEquals(20, x.getJ());
}
```